# StringGrid scrollbars always visible

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, stringgrid

I'm programming in Delphi and I want to have a vertical Scrollbar that is always visible, even if the number of rows is 1 (the DefaultDrawing option is not active, i'm using Canvas to draw the cells).

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You need to customize the control. Or use a different control

Comment: Just of curiosity, may I ask why? Has it something to do with you yourself drawing the cells?

Comment: @TomBrunberg it's usually a matter of trying to find the ideal default widths of the columns in a string grid. If you do that taking the width of the scroll bar into account, it looks terrible if there is no scroll bar. (been there, done that)

Answer (score 1):

You could interpose `TStringGrid` and override the `Resize` method, like so:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Grids;

type
  TStringGrid = class(Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid)
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TStringGrid }

procedure TStringGrid.Resize;
begin
  inherited Resize;
  ShowScrollBar(Handle, SB_VERT, True);
end;

end.
```

A minor test with anchors set gives good results here.